# Fourier transform and locality/uncertainty

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Could you explain a bit about the relationship between locality and uncertainty in Fourier pairs? 
Many pages talk about uncertainty principle stating that the precision at which we can measure time duration of signal cannot unlimitedly grow without affecting precision on bandwidth.
Many other pages talk about the lower bound on time duration and bandwidth product themselves, not uncertainties about them.
What's exactly the link between them?

Furthermore, does the uncertainty principle forbid signal with unlimited time and bandwidth? I am talking about effective duration and effective bandwidth.

EDIT: trying to understand this principle using common sense from fourier scaling rules, I cannot guess why this is a lower bound instead of a theta bound..

Comment: In the extreme case each instantaneous frequency in the Fourier transform corresponds to a sine wave of some phase which has unlimited reach in time. To go from there with the objective to shorten the wave we need to start including more frequencies.

Comment: As an experiment multiply a sine with a box function, what happens in the fourier domain is convolution with a sinc, which will blur out the frequency. Even though it is a well defined sine wave for a well defined time interval, the violent discontinous "cutting effects" of multiplying with the box function forces the representation of the sine to be spread out all over the spectrum as fast as we consider any interval of time outside of it's reach.

Comment: @mathreadler do you maybe have an explanation why the Heisenberg uncertainty principle in general prevents the existence of a function which tells me for a particular point in time what the frequency spectrum of my function is at this point in time?